# Why is this Vagrant / Ansible Ruby loop executed twice and variable changes not respected?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

I'm new to Vagrant / Ansible / Ruby and I don't know why an inner loop seems to be being executed twice and why an outer loop doesn't respect changes to variables made within the inner loop.

I want to have a dynamic inventory file and I want to put some config values into a config file that is loaded by Vagrant that will create this for me.  I want to define a number of groups with a similar structure that will define how many hosts within each group are created by Vagrant.

```
---
# vagrant.yml  
general:
  base_ip: "192.168.2"
  vm_box: "ubuntu/trusty64"

virtualbox:
  vb_gui: true
  vb_memory: 2048
  vb_cpus: 1

groupA:
  num_nodes: 1
  instance_name_prefix: "groupA"
  base_ip_offset: 50

groupB:
  num_nodes: 0
  instance_name_prefix: "groupB"
  base_ip_offset: 60
```

I want to iterate through each group and create `num_nodes` instances within that group using Vagrant.  Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'yaml'
settings = YAML.load_file 'vagrant.yml'

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = settings['general']['vm_box']

  ansible_groups = [
    "groupA",
    "groupB"
  ]

  # this counter should just represent which machine we are configuring out of the total
  # population of all machines across all groups
  # i.e. it should be monotonically increasing from 0..totalNumberOfNodes 
  machine_counter = 0

  ansible_groups.each do |group|
    num_nodes = settings[group]['num_nodes'].to_i
    (1..num_nodes).each do |i|
      config.vm.define vm_name = "%s-%02d" % [settings[group]['instance_name_prefix'], i]
      config.vm.hostname = vm_name

      config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.gui = settings['virtualbox']['vb_gui']
        vb.memory = settings['virtualbox']['vb_memory']
        vb.cpus = settings['virtualbox']['vb_cpus']
      end

      ip = "#{settings['general']['base_ip']}.#{settings[group]['base_ip_offset'].to_i + i}"
      config.vm.network :private_network, ip: ip

      config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 2001, host: 10000 + 2001 + machine_counter
      machine_counter = machine_counter + 1

      config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
#        ansible.verbose = "vvvv"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

At the moment, groupB is empty (num_nodes is 0), and everything works fine.  Here is the output from `vagrant up --no-provision`:

```
$ vagrant up --no-provision
Bringing machine 'groupA-01' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> groupA-01: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> groupA-01: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> groupA-01: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> groupA-01: Setting the name of the VM: demo_groupA-01_1442511426046_79038
==> groupA-01: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> groupA-01: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> groupA-01: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    groupA-01: Adapter 1: nat
    groupA-01: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> groupA-01: Forwarding ports...
    groupA-01: 2001 => 12001 (adapter 1)
    groupA-01: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> groupA-01: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> groupA-01: Booting VM...
==> groupA-01: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    groupA-01: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    groupA-01: SSH username: vagrant
    groupA-01: SSH auth method: private key
    groupA-01: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    groupA-01: 
    groupA-01: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    groupA-01: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    groupA-01: 
    groupA-01: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    groupA-01: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    groupA-01: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> groupA-01: Machine booted and ready!
==> groupA-01: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> groupA-01: Setting hostname...
==> groupA-01: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> groupA-01: Mounting shared folders...
    groupA-01: /vagrant => /Users/me/demo
==> groupA-01: Machine not provisioned because `--no-provision` is specified.
```

Now, when I add another machine to the config (`num_nodes` within `groupA` is 2), I get the ports forwarded twice and the ports are forwarded to the same values for the second machine, resulting in a failure:

```
$ vagrant up --no-provision
Bringing machine 'groupA-01' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'groupA-02' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> groupA-01: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> groupA-01: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> groupA-01: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> groupA-01: Setting the name of the VM: demo_ groupA-01_1442512392590_86418
==> groupA-01: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> groupA-01: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> groupA-01: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    groupA-01: Adapter 1: nat
    groupA-01: Adapter 2: hostonly
    groupA-01: Adapter 3: hostonly
==> groupA-01: Forwarding ports...
    groupA-01: 2001 => 12001 (adapter 1)
    groupA-01: 2001 => 12002 (adapter 1)
    groupA-01: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> groupA-01: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> groupA-01: Booting VM...
==> groupA-01: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    groupA-01: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    groupA-01: SSH username: vagrant
    groupA-01: SSH auth method: private key
    groupA-01: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    groupA-01: 
    groupA-01: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    groupA-01: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    groupA-01: 
    groupA-01: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    groupA-01: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    groupA-01: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> groupA-01: Machine booted and ready!
==> groupA-01: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> groupA-01: Setting hostname...
==> groupA-01: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> groupA-01: Mounting shared folders...
    groupA-01: /vagrant => /Users/john/travelnet/kafka-samza2
==> groupA-01: Machine not provisioned because `--no-provision` is specified.
==> groupA-02: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> groupA-02: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> groupA-02: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> groupA-02: Setting the name of the VM: demo_ groupA-02_1442512426303_57538
==> groupA-02: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening
on these ports. The forwarded port to 12001 is already in use
on the host machine.

To fix this, modify your current projects Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 2001, host: 1234

Sometimes, Vagrant will attempt to auto-correct this for you. In this
case, Vagrant was unable to. This is usually because the guest machine
is in a state which doesn't allow modifying port forwarding.
```

The port forwarding section is being executed twice (as is the provisioning section, if I don't use `--no-provision`).

I don't understand why it is being executed twice, nor why for the second VM, it is attempting to forward to 12001 (I think it should be to 12002, which should be ok, because the first VM should only be forwarding to 12001).

There is a warning about lazy loading with Vagrant loops here: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/tips.html, but I'm new to Ruby and I don't see how/why that applies here.

The loop I am trying to achieve is:

```
For each group within groups:
    For each node in 1..num_nodes within group:
        Configure node
```

What's going on here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that there is nothing wrong here with ruby.

The problem is that you're only using one machine. If you want multiple machines within Vagrant you need to follow: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/

A non-tested approach of what you want to do (notice this_vm instead of config):

```
(1..num_nodes).each do |i|
  vm_name = "%s-%02d" % [settings[group]['instance_name_prefix'], i]
  config.vm.define vm_name do |this_vm|
    this_vm.vm.hostname = vm_name

    this_vm.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.gui = settings['virtualbox']['vb_gui']
      vb.memory = settings['virtualbox']['vb_memory']
      vb.cpus = settings['virtualbox']['vb_cpus']
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks very much, you're spot on.  Using your suggestion, I eventually came across this in the documentation (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html): "As you can see, config.vm.define takes a block with another variable. This variable, such as [an example the docs cite] above, is the exact same as the config variable, except any configuration of the inner variable applies only to the machine being defined."